# Graph flow chart

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to reproduce this figure using Mathematica. I am not even sure it is possible. Maybe `Graph` approach can be used.

[image]

Here is my starting point.

```
greenRed = 
  Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0.5}, {17, 16}], Darker@Green, 
    Table[Rectangle[{0, i}, {9, i + 1}], {i, 1, 15, 1.5}], Red, 
    Table[Rectangle[{i + 9.5, 0.5}, {i + 10.5, 16}], {i, 0, 6, 1.5}]},
    AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> None];

redGreen = 
  Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0.5}, {17, 16}], Red, 
    Table[Rectangle[{i + 0.5, 0.5}, {i + 1.5, 16}], {i, 0, 6, 1.5}], 
    Darker@Green, 
    Table[Rectangle[{8., i}, {17, i + 1}], {i, 1, 15, 1.5}]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> None];

greenGreen = 
  Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0.5}, {17, 16}], Darker@Green, 
    Table[Rectangle[{0, i}, {17, i + 1}], {i, 1, 15, 1.5}]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> None];

redRed = Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0.5}, {17, 16}], Red, 
    Table[Rectangle[{i + 0.5, 0.5}, {i + 1.5, 16}], {i, 0, 16, 1.5}]},
    AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> None];

red = Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0.5}, {17, 16}], Red, 
    Table[Rectangle[{i + 0.5, 0.5}, {i + 1.5, 16}], {i, 0, 6, 1.5}], 
    White, Rectangle[{8, 0.5}, {17, 16}]}, AspectRatio -> 1];

green = Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0.5}, {17, 16}], Darker@Green, 
    Table[Rectangle[{0, i}, {9, i + 1}], {i, 1, 15, 1.5}], White, 
    Rectangle[{9, 0.5}, {17, 16}]}, AspectRatio -> 1];

mat={{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
AdjacencyGraph[mat, 
 VertexShape -> {1 -> greenRed, 2 -> redGreen, 3 -> green, 4 -> red, 
   5 -> red, 6 -> green, 7 -> greenRed, 8 -> greenGreen, 9 -> redRed, 
   10 -> redGreen}, VertexSize -> 0.5]
```

I don't know how to plot flow lines. Any suggestion?

Comment: "I am not even sure it is possible." It is certainly possible. Anything can be built from graphics primitives. But Mathematica is not the right tool for this. You could make this in yEd ten times faster.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for the graph editor. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
AdjacencyGraph[mat, ImagePadding -> 40, VertexSize -> 0.5, 
  VertexShape -> vshapes, EdgeLabels -> elabels, 
  VertexLabels -> vlabels, EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeshapefuncs, 
  VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

where `vshapes`, `elabels`, `vlabels`, `edshapefunctions` and `vcoords` are defined below.

First, shapes `red` and `green` are modified to remove the white parts:

```
red2 = Graphics[{Red, Table[Rectangle[{i + 0.5, 0.5}, {i + 1.5, 16}], {i, 0, 6, 1.5}]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 2, Background -> Black];
green2 = Graphics[{Darker@Green, Table[Rectangle[{0, i}, {9, i + 1}], {i, 1, 15, 1.5}]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 2, Background -> Black];

vshapes = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, {greenRed, redGreen, green2, red2, red2, 
    green2, greenRed, greenGreen, redRed, redGreen}];
```

Vertex and edge labels are straightforward:

```
vlabels = MapThread[# -> Placed[Style["percept " <> #2, 14], Above] &, 
  {{7, 8, 9, 10}, {"1", "3", "2", "4"}}];
elabels = {DirectedEdge[3, 4] -> Placed[Style["α", 20], {1/2, {1/2, 0}}], 
   DirectedEdge[4, 5] -> Placed[Style["β", 20], {1/2, {1/2, 0}}]};
```

We get the vertex layout by transforming `GraphEmbedding[CompleteGraph[{2, 4, 4}]]`:

```
vcoords = ScalingTransform[{-1, 1}]@
   RotationTransform[Pi/2][GraphEmbedding[CompleteGraph[{2, 4, 4}]]];
vcoords[[{1, 2}]] = ScalingTransform[{2, 1}][vcoords[[{1, 2}]]];
```

Finally we make edge `3 -> 6` curved to avoid edge overlaps

```
AdjacencyGraph[mat, ImagePadding -> 40, VertexSize -> 0.5, 
 VertexShape -> vshapes, EdgeLabels -> elabels, 
 VertexLabels -> vlabels, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, ImageSize -> 400, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {DirectedEdge[3, 6] -> {"CurvedEdge", "Curvature" -> .7}}]
```

[image]

Getting the edge shapes and layout is manual:

```
ClearAll[dotArrow]
dotArrow[setback_: {.06, .06}, color_: Lighter[Blue]] := {Thickness[.01], Opacity[1], 
  color, JoinForm["Round"], (GraphElementData["DotLine"][##]/. BezierCurve->Line)  /. 
    {Arrowheads[{{a_, b_, {c_, d_}}}] :> Arrowheads[{{a, 1, {c, d}}, {-a, 0, {c, d}}}], 
     Arrow[x_] :> Arrow[x, setback]}} &

edgeshapefuncs = {_ :> (dotArrow[][{1, .95} # & /@ #[[{1, -1}]], ##2]&),
   DirectedEdge[1, 4] | DirectedEdge[2, 5] | DirectedEdge[5, 9] :> dotArrow[ {0, .12}],
   DirectedEdge[4, 5] -> (dotArrow[.06, Orange][{1, .95} # & /@ #[[{1, -1}]], ##2] &),
   DirectedEdge[3, 6] -> (dotArrow[.12, Orange][{#[[1]], {#[[1, 1]], 1.25 #[[1, 2]]}, 
      {#[[2, 1]], 1.25 #[[2, 2]]}, #[[-1]]}, ##2] &),
   DirectedEdge[3, 7] | DirectedEdge[6, 10] :> 
     (dotArrow[{0, .06}][{#[[1]], {1.5 #[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}, {1.5 #[[2, 1]], #[[2, 2]]},
        {1.1, 1} #[[-1]]}, ##2] &),
   DirectedEdge[1, 3] | DirectedEdge[1,4]|DirectedEdge[2,5]|DirectedEdge[2, 6] :>       
     (dotArrow[{0, .12}][{#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}, #[[-1]]}, ##2] &),
   DirectedEdge[3, 8] | DirectedEdge[5, 10] | DirectedEdge[4, 9] :> 
     (dotArrow[ {0, .12}][{{1, 1.05} #[[1]], 
        {2/3 #[[1, 1]] + 1/3 #[[-1, 1]], 1.05 #[[1, 2]]}, 
        {2/3 #[[1, 1]] + 1/3 #[[-1, 1]], #[[2, 2]]}, #[[-1]]}, ##2] &),
   DirectedEdge[4, 7] :> (dotArrow[ {0, .12}][{{1, 1.05} #[[1]], 
        {2/3 #[[1, 1]] + 1/3 #[[-1, 1]], 1.05 #[[1, 2]]},
        {2/3 #[[1, 1]] + 1/3 #[[-1, 1]],  Mean[#[[{1, -1}, 2]]]},
        {#[[2, 1]], Mean[#[[{1, -1}, 2]]]}, #[[-1]]}, ##2] &),
   DirectedEdge[6, 8] :> (dotArrow[ {0, .12}][{{1, 1.05} #[[1]],
        {5/6 #[[1, 1]] + 1/6 #[[-1, 1]], 1.05 #[[1, 2]]}, 
        {5/6 #[[1, 1]] + 1/6 #[[-1, 1]], Mean[#[[{1, -1}, 2]]]}, 
        {#[[2, 1]], Mean[#[[{1, -1}, 2]]]}, #[[-1]]}, ##2] &)};
```

Comment: @Okkes, now it works in v12 (wolfram Cloud). The issue was that, in version 12, the built-in function `GraphElementData["DotLine"]` produces `BezierCurves` when its first argument has more than 2 points. Replacing `BezierCurve` with `Line` fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks kglr. One more request. How to connect 1-4 and 2-5 from the side as in the original figure? I could not figure it out.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci, please see the new version.

Comment: Excellent!! Bottom 2 vertices seem too far from  Level 1. Is it possible to shorten?

Comment: @Okkes, try `SetProperty[ag, {VertexCoordinates->{v:(1|2) :> TranslationTransform[{0, .5}] @ ScalingTransform[{2, 1}][PropertyValue[{ag, v}, VertexCoordinates]]}}]` in the last line.